# Modifying toc in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have found out that, in KOMA-Script, I can modify the TOC (see [the KOMA-manual, page 72](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf)). It can be done by using the option `toc`.

However, how do I use this option? To which command do I have to add it?
And (teaching a man to fish) - how can I find this out from the manual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add option `toc=<value>` as class option

```
\documentclass[toc=<value>]{<KOMA-Script class>}
```

or later using

```
\KOMAoptions{toc=<value>}
```

or you can use

```
\KOMAoption{toc}{<value list>}
```

---

Examples:

```
\documentclass[toc=flat,toc=listof]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{toc=flat,toc=listof}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{toc}{flat,listof}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results all in

[image]

---

There is a table with all possible values of option `toc` in the documentation (»Table 3.5.: Available values of the toc option to set the format and contents of the table of contents«).

More information regarding the setting of KOMA-Script options can be found eg in section »3.1. Early or Late Selection of Options«.

---

Additional remark:

Note that the KOMA-Script classes load and use package `tocbasic` for the TOC, LOF, LOT and maybe other lists. So you could also use the macros and settings of `tocbasic` to modify TOC entries. See »Chapter 15: Managing Content Lists with tocbasic« in »Part II. KOMA -Script for Advanced Users and Experts«.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in chapter 3.9 you can read:

> 3.9. Table of Contents The title and optional abstract are normally followed by a table of contents. Often you also find additional lists
>   of the floating environments, such as tables and figures, after the
>   table of contents (see section 3.20). In addition to the options
>   documented in this section,

The last sentence tells it to you: chapter 3 discussed the main classes and `toc` is a class option for them ...

So try the follwing MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, 
  div=12,
  toc=left % <==========================================================
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % dummy text

\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

you get the toc:

[image]

Change the option for `toc=bibliographynumbered` you get the following resulting toc:

[image]